# Floating environment with horizontal line using KOMA-script's `DeclareNewTOC`

Tags: floats, koma-script, algorithmicx

**Short Version:**

I want to define a new floating environment using `DeclareNewTOC` which is enclosed by horizontal lines.

**Long Version:**

I use the package `algpseudocode` for typesetting my algorithms. Since `algpseudocode` does not provide a floating environment one can use the environment from the older `algorithm` package. This package produces in combination with chapter heading/labeling the warning `Class scrbook Warning: \float@addtolists detected!`. Of course, this warning can be avoided using the package `scrhack`.

In the following the minimal example which demonstrate this behavior:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

% \usepackage{scrhack}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter Heading}
\label{ch:1}

\end{document}
```

Since KOMA-scripts provides `DeclareNewTOC`, I though I could use this command to define a new environment for that purpose. This works quit well except for the horizontal lines. I tried `\hrulefill` and some other commands but the spacing was not satisfying. In the following the minimal example using `DeclareNewTOC`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\DeclareNewTOC[
type=algorithm,
float,
floatpos=h,
name=Algorithm,
counterwithin=chapter]
{loalg}
% \usepackage{scrhack}
% \usepackage{algorithm}

\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Caption for algorithm 1.}
  \label{alg:alg1}
  \begin{algorithmic}[0]
    \For{$i = 0$ to $10$}
    \If{$i$ is odd}
    \State $x_i \gets 1$
    \EndIf
    \EndFor 
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

The output of the minimal example and the output which I am targeting based on the `algorithm` package. I want at least the line between the caption and at the end of the code.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use key `atbegin` to patch environment `algorithmic` inside environment `algorithm`.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\DeclareNewTOC[
type=algorithm,
float,
floatpos=h,
name=Algorithm,
counterwithin=chapter,
atbegin={%
  %\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{.8pt}\vspace{-\baselineskip}% rule at begin of algorithm
  \xpretocmd\algorithmic
    {\noindent\rule[\ht\strutbox]{\linewidth}{.8pt}\vspace{-\baselineskip}}
    {}{\PatchFailed}%
  \xapptocmd\endalgorithmic
    {\noindent\rule[\ht\strutbox]{\linewidth}{.8pt}\vspace{-\baselineskip}}
    {}{\PatchFailed}%
}
]
{loalg}

\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter Heading}
\label{ch:1}

\blindtext

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Caption for algorithm 1.}
  \label{alg:alg1}
  \begin{algorithmic}[0]
    \For{$i = 0$ to $10$}
    \If{$i$ is odd}
    \State $x_i \gets 1$
    \EndIf
    \EndFor 
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\blindtext

\begin{algorithmic}[0]
  \For{$i = 0$ to $10$}
  \If{$i$ is odd}
  \State $x_i \gets 1$
  \EndIf
  \EndFor 
\end{algorithmic}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

You can also insert a line at the beginning of `algorithm` using:

```
atbegin={%
  \noindent\rule{\linewidth}{.8pt}\vspace{-\baselineskip}% rule at begin of algorithm
  ...
}
```

[image]

Without this line you could (or should) use

```
\captionabove{Caption for algorithm 1.}
```

instead `\caption{...}`:

[image]

Maybe you do not want that environment `algorithm` floats (because you are using `floatpos=h`). Then you can use option `nonfloat` and environment `algorithm-`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\DeclareNewTOC[
type=algorithm,
nonfloat,
name=Algorithm,
counterwithin=chapter,
atbegin={%
  %\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{.8pt}\vspace{-\baselineskip}% rule at begin of algorithm
  \xpretocmd\algorithmic
    {\noindent\rule[\ht\strutbox]{\linewidth}{.8pt}\vspace{-\baselineskip}}
    {}{\PatchFailed}%
  \xapptocmd\endalgorithmic
    {\noindent\rule[\ht\strutbox]{\linewidth}{.8pt}\vspace{-\baselineskip}}
    {}{\PatchFailed}%
}
]
{loalg}

\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter Heading}
\label{ch:1}

\blindtext

\begin{algorithm-}
  \captionabove{Caption for algorithm 1.}
  \label{alg:alg1}
  \begin{algorithmic}[0]
    \For{$i = 0$ to $10$}
    \If{$i$ is odd}
    \State $x_i \gets 1$
    \EndIf
    \EndFor 
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm-}

\blindtext

\begin{algorithmic}[0]
  \For{$i = 0$ to $10$}
  \If{$i$ is odd}
  \State $x_i \gets 1$
  \EndIf
  \EndFor 
\end{algorithmic}

\end{document}
```

---

**Update** (because of a comment below)

If all captions of the new environment should use the spacing like captions above floats, the `atbegin` option of `\DeclareNewTOC` can be used to set KOMA-option `captions=heading` for this new environment.

```
\DeclareNewTOC[...,
atbegin={\KOMAoptions{captions=heading}% 
  ...},
...]{loalg}
```

Then it is possible to use `\caption` instead `\captionabove` to get the same spacing.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\DeclareNewTOC[
type=algorithm,
float,
floatpos=h,
name=Algorithm,
counterwithin=chapter,
atbegin={%
  \KOMAoptions{captions=heading}% <- added
  \xpretocmd\algorithmic
    {\noindent\rule[\ht\strutbox]{\linewidth}{.8pt}\vspace{-\baselineskip}}
    {}{\PatchFailed}%
  \xapptocmd\endalgorithmic
    {\noindent\rule[\ht\strutbox]{\linewidth}{.8pt}\vspace{-\baselineskip}}
    {}{\PatchFailed}%
}
]
{loalg}

\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter Heading}
\label{ch:1}

\blindtext

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Caption for algorithm 1.}% <- caption with spacing like captionabove
  \label{alg:alg1}
  \begin{algorithmic}[0]
    \For{$i = 0$ to $10$}
    \If{$i$ is odd}
    \State $x_i \gets 1$
    \EndIf
    \EndFor 
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\blindtext

\begin{algorithmic}[0]
  \For{$i = 0$ to $10$}
  \If{$i$ is odd}
  \State $x_i \gets 1$
  \EndIf
  \EndFor 
\end{algorithmic}

\end{document}
```

Comment: When the top line is not used, you advise to use `\captionabove` instead of `\caption`. I fully agree. Is there any way to automatically set proper spacing for captions above the float with `\DeclareNewTOC`? Something similar is already possible with the KOMA-Script package option `tableabove` for table captions. This allows to use `\caption` instead of `\captionabove` in table environments.

Comment: Use `atbegin={\KOMAoptions{headings=above}...}` in the settings of `loalg`, see my updated answer.

Comment: Great, that is exactly what I was looking for.